# Cocos 2d CCMenu to appear

Tags: ccmenuitem, coco2d-x

I want to use a image for 80 times (same Image) Instead of adding CCMenu 80 time there is any alternate way.

```
CCMenuItemImage tile=CCMenuItemImage.item("1.png","1.png");
tile.setScaleX(1.0f);
tile.setScaleY(1.0f);
tile.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(screenSize.width-630*generalscalefactor,405));
```